# Ember-Data, embedded relation records and server JSON response

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Working on an App with Ember RC6 and Ember-Data v0.13-54 along a custom server PHP API am running into some problems with Models relations (mainly many-to-many) and side loading.

The models in questions are:

```
App.Member = DS.Model.extend({
  apiToken: DS.attr('string'),
  apiTokenExpire: DS.attr('string'),
  favourites: DS.hasMany('App.Presentation')
});

App.Presentation = DS.Model.extend(
{
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  date: DS.attr('date'),

  category: DS.belongsTo('App.Category'),
  tags: DS.hasMany('App.Tag'),
  employees: DS.hasMany('App.Member'),

  presentation: DS.belongsTo('App.File'),
  presenterNotes: DS.belongsTo('App.File'),
  cover: DS.belongsTo('App.Image')
});
```

To get the RESTAdapater to send the relation with the `Member` model I have:

```
App.APIRESTAdapter.map('App.Member', {
  favourites: {embedded: 'always'}
});
```

When loading `/members/1` the server returns:

```
{
  "member": {
    "api_token": "9fa236ad58726584d7b61bcf94b4dda37cbd3a24",
    "api_token_expire": "1383832335",
    "id": 1,
    "favourite_ids": [ 3 ],
    "group_ids": [ 2 ]
  },
  "presentations": [
    {
      "title": "That's a new one!",
      "category_id": 2,
      "id": 3,
      "tag_ids": [ 1 ],
      "employee_ids": [ 1 ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But if I log `get('member.favourites').mapProperty('id')` I get an empty array and none of the `favourites` are actually added to the `Member` model.

If I disable the embedding of `favourites` on the RESTAdapter, all works fine. I am just wondering if there is something that I am missing or if there is some issues with how the JSON response is formatted?

---

**EDIT:**

Done some digging and seems that the issue comes from the fact that the relation names (*favourites*, *employees*) is different from the model names (*Member*, *Presentation*) which are used when sideloading data. Weird, since rev. 12 https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/BREAKING_CHANGES.md models should be Sideload by Type.

Doing some tests I've added a new many-to-many relation for those 2 models:

`App.Member` gets `presentations: DS.hasMany('App.Presentation')`

`App.Presentation` get `members: DS.hasMany('App.Member')`

The JSON returned by the server is exactly the same, and when logging `get('member.presentations')` I now get the list of presentations as it should.

At this point this looks like a bug to me, but maybe am missing something? I've tried mappings on the `RESTAdapater` for *favourites* and *employees* but that didn't help... Maybe there is some other Adapter config that could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a *sideloading* issue but more a misunderstanding on my side about *embedded* data and what the configuration meant.
Since the Adapter was configured with:

```
App.APIRESTAdapter.map('App.Member', {
  favourites: {embedded: 'always'}
});
```

The expected JSON response from the server is:

```
{
  "member": {
    "api_token": "b84fd204b37d3fa3cee8a2b2cac8bd4fd02635a1",
    "api_token_expire": "1384027367",
    "id": 1,
    "favourites": [
      {
        "title": "Some kind of title",
        "category_id": 1,
        "id": 2,
        "tag_ids": [ 1 , 2 ],
        "employee_ids": [ 1 ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So `"favourite_ids": [ X, X, X ]` should have been `"favourites": [ HASH, HASH, HASH ]` when records are flagged as embedded.